# JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jwt, restful-authentication

I have this class that uses JSON Web Token Support For The JVM to create and validate JWT tokens

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3301605592208950415L;

    private Clock clock = DefaultClock.INSTANCE;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    private Long expiration;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getIssuedAtDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getIssuedAt);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(secret)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(clock.now());
    }

    private Boolean isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(Date created, Date lastPasswordReset) {
        return (lastPasswordReset != null && created.before(lastPasswordReset));
    }

    private Boolean ignoreTokenExpiration(String token) {
        return false;
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        final Date createdDate = clock.now();
        final Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setIssuedAt(createdDate)
            .setExpiration(expirationDate)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
            .compact();
    }

    public Boolean canTokenBeRefreshed(String token, Date lastPasswordReset) {
        final Date created = getIssuedAtDateFromToken(token);
        return !isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(created, lastPasswordReset)
            && (!isTokenExpired(token) || ignoreTokenExpiration(token));
    }

    public String refreshToken(String token) {
        final Date createdDate = clock.now();
        final Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        claims.setIssuedAt(createdDate);
        claims.setExpiration(expirationDate);

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
            .compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
            User user = (User) userDetails;
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        final Date created = getIssuedAtDateFromToken(token);

        return (
            username.equals(user.getUsername())
                && !isTokenExpired(token)
                && !isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(created, user.getLastPasswordResetDate())
        );
    }

    private Date calculateExpirationDate(Date createdDate) {
        return new Date(createdDate.getTime() + expiration * 1000);
    }
}
```

But I got this error when validating a token:

```
2018-12-27 16:57 [http-nio-1133-exec-6] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log(175) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/iCrypts] threw exception
io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:235)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)
    at com.tdk.security.JwtTokenUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:55)
    at com.tdk.security.JwtTokenUtil.getClaimFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:48)
    at com.tdk.security.JwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:36)
    at com.tdk.security.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: is it working for you ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sender of token is not properly setting the token in header, format is Authentication: Bearer your.jwt.token.

If bearer is present remove it from the token and than pass it to JWT process engine.

Comment: In my case, the sender concatenates the same jwtToken for three times. Then backend threw MalformateException.